# Trying to check if two expressions are equal

Tags: expression-test

So I am trying to check if two expressions are the same. I have seen multiple posts on how we can just put expression 1 == expression 2 and Mathematica returns true or false. This works for a simple example: 3==5 gives false, as it should.

But lately, when I am putting two expressions equal I just get the two expressions as output? They all have the same variables and functions, so how can I make Mathematica understand?

A basic example is putting 3x == x 3, Mathematica will not understand this either. Any ideas on what to do to compare expressions?

Answer (score 2):

"12.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 12, 2020)"

in my case your example works fine. Try appending `//FullSimplify`

Comment: Windows, 12.1, same here.